Connect DBeaver to AWS RDS Postgres
Please can you help me. I try to connect to postgres database in AWS.
I set up the dBeaver but still i get the timeout.
RDS Settings

Configuration

VPC Settings

Security group

Settings in dBeaver

Maybe the problem is there, but how i can change the GRANT if i have no access to db


Sorry, but you have not provided enough information for us to be able to assist you. Is your Amazon RDS database set to Publicly Available = Yes? What is the configuration of the security group on the database? Have you ever managed to connect to the database using some other method? Please Edit your Question to provide additional information.

yes sorry i didn't added the screens. I do it know. I think everthing is set up correct ...

Is the database still running? When I try to ping echarita-test-02.cuoo091oacuk.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com, it says Unknown host. This means the DNS name is not resolving.

no ti was stoped. I have started it again. Now you can see the (ping echarita-test-02.cuoo091oacuk.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com) the response is Ping wird ausgeführt für ec2-35-159-100-45.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com [35.159.100.45] mit 32 Bytes Daten: Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.

A timeout indicates a network connectivity problem whereas a quick response means that it is communicating but Postgres is refusing your connection. When I try to connect, it takes a long time to fail. Therefore, there is no network connectivity. Check the Subnet Group assigned to the database -- it is possible that the database was launched in a private subnet so it is not reachable from the Internet. Also, see if you followed the steps shown here: Unable to connect to public RDS instance

I think it is not the problem. I have created also the EC2 instance in this VPC and this subnet and I can log in (via SSH). There is really only issue with RDS

Only remaining thing to check is that you have not modified the Network ACL settings from their default "Allow All" configuration.

After some days of investigation I found (maybe) the reason.
It seems, that the some subnets was private. After i have created the only public subnets it is fine.

As you use Postgresql 16 RDS might require you to use SSL to connect to your DB.

The default rds.force_ssl parameter is set to 1 (on) for RDS for PostgreSQL version 15.

Check this parameter if your RDS requires to use of SSL.
How to connect with SSL or disable this restriction you can find here in docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html
